# RTSP handshake - bad request

Tags: udp, video-streaming, rtsp, rtp

I have issue with proxying rtsp stream. I'm trying to proxy stream from one camera (using mediamtx), and when CCTV server connects to mediamtx i'm getting error.
I'm quite shure that I'm missing something in mediamtx configuration. Idea is to implement 3rd party camera to Pelco compatible CCTV server.

here is Wireshark TCP stream:
[image]

and here is example of TCP stream from same CCTV server connected directly to camera:
[image]
can someone shed some light on this?

mediamtx is running on windows.
Maybe I'm using wrong tool for this, or I'm just missing something obvious.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first case, SETUP request ask for an aggregate operation on stream1 which contains one video and one metadata stream from what i see in the SDP and the request looks syntaxically correct.

However control fields are defined at the media session level which means you need to use those urls to establish separate RTSP control session for each stream or the stream you are interested in (like the video stream in your second example).

My guess is that the server does not support it and may have returned an error 459 ( Aggregate Operation Not Allowed) instead to be more explicit.

Comment: thanks for shedding some light on this. after longer examination of this issue, i'm confirming that server does not support this.